# Acceptable wildcards in PathPattern for AWS Cloudfront CacheBehavior

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, browser-cache

Trying to set the cache behaviors for a path in our app, AWS docs only show examples of trailing wildcards (i.e. `/images/*`, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-cachebehavior.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-cachebehavior-pathpattern, and also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern).

However we use a path pattern that implements language variables before the rest of the path so like (`/{language}/product/{productId}`).

Is it acceptable, in the cloud formation template to set the PathPattern with a wildcard in each variable spot?

I.e. `/*/product/*`.

If not and I use `/product/*` I believe only routes like `https://website.com/product/{productId}` will be picked up by cloudfront to analyze and a route like `https://website.com/en/product/{productId}` would be missed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/*/product/*` is valid, and correct, for  `https://example.com/en/product/{productId}`.

Perhaps even more correct would be `/??/product/*` since `?` matches exactly 1 character, while `*` matches 0 or more.

`/product/*` would not match the example given.

Remember also that CloudFront matches requests against path patterns in precedence order, so the "first match" (in precedence order) always wins -- there is not a concept of "best match" or ambuguous/non-deterministic path pattern matching.

Comment: What determines precedence order?

Comment: @nealsu cache behaviors on a CloudFront distribution are an ordered list, and this order is the matching/precedence order.  *"If you create additional cache behaviors, the default cache behavior is always the last to be processed. Other cache behaviors are processed in the order in which they're listed in the CloudFront console or, if you're using the CloudFront API, the order in which they're listed in the DistributionConfig element for the distribution."* -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesCacheBehavior